# The best way of selecting div

Tags: jquery

I want to add to div#container a div inside another div and then get selector of the inner div. Which one is the better way to do this?

```
$('#container').html("<div><div class='get'></div></div>");
var div = $('#container').find('.get');
```

or

```
var div = $('<div></div>');
$('#container').html(
    $('<div></div>').html(div)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter.  In the first example you are traversing a lot more (because of the `find`) than in the second example, which has some performance implications.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Using jquery object inside .html() doesn't cause any problems for me.

Comment: It wasn't working for me like that in JSFiddle, but perhaps I was using the wrong markup.  If it works for you, then definitely stick with the second one. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = $('<div />');
$('#container').html('').append(div);
```

I don't think you can use jQuery object as argument for `html()`

Comment: Why do you call `html()` with an empty argument?

Comment: @AaronDigulla append alone would add to the existing content, based on the sample code given by OP, he wants to replace the whole HTML with the new div, thus I'm clearing it using '', it's not empty, it's an argument of empty string

Answer (score 0):

Either way is absolutely fine. I would probably use the second way if you're adding elements, it just seems a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Either method will work, but the first method uses the same selector twice. better practice would be

```
var con = $('#container').html("<div><div class='get'></div></div>");
var div = con.find('.get');
```